# Checking a table for time overlaps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem with my custom validation. There is individual_trainings table.

```
# Table name: individual_trainings
#
#  id               :integer          not null, primary key
#  date_of_training :date             not null
#  client_id        :integer
#  trainer_id       :integer
#  end_on           :time             not null
#  training_cost_id :integer
#  start_on         :time             not null
```

I want to create validation method that checks if client has another training on the same day and time start_on, end_on overlaps with another training throw error.

```
  def client_individual_training_validation
    client.individual_trainings_as_client.where('date_of_training = ?', date_of_training).each do |ci|
      if (start_on...end_on).overlaps?(ci.start_on...ci.end_on)
        errors.add(:error, 'You have a training in the same time.')
      end
    end
  end
```

There is a problem with this method, because if new date and time is correct(not overlap), create method passes and add new training in database.but also there is a alert error message, that term is already busy. How to fix it?

Comment: I'm confused. You're saying that even if the data passes validation, it still contains the `'You have a training in the same time.'` error?!

Comment: @TomLord Yes, that's right if I put in form invalid data, that overlaps with another I have twice error message You have a training in the same time.  I supose that validation executes twice times.

Comment: How are you saving the data, and calling this validator? Are you doing anything funny, such as `update_attributes`, or `save(validate: false)`, or calling the validator multiple times, .....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#errors), errors should be like `errors[: attribute]` or `errors[:base]`.

Since there isn't an attribute names `error`, the validator will ignore this line

```
errors.add(:error, 'You have a training in the same time.')
```

Try this

```
errors.add(:base, 'You have a training in the same time.')
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#errors